# Linux Server HDD Corrupted

Tags: linux, hard-drive, centos5, corruption

Today I put my forum offline just before scheduled Cpanel backup. An hour later when I checked it says DATABASE error occured(or whatever the database error was) I logged into SSH and perform reboot. The server will not reboot sucessfully.
I contacted my host and  they are saying: "
Looks like the drive is corrupt, it is failing to boot and BIOS hangs when detecting the drive. We will have to replace the drive and install the OS again. "

I do have Secondary HDD where I used to save all the backups.

What should my next step be? I have other websites and a lot of data on that server... If I loose everything that means all attachments and everything is gone.

They have OnePortal thing where HOST is suggesting me to check what do I have on my secondaryHDD...

Can someone please suggest next steps

Comment: They reason why I posted it here to find out a way to recover data on corrupted drive. I did have backups on secondary drive. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the failed drive replaced, and then restore your backups. Pretty straightforward, if annoying.

Comment: I can't afford to loose any data on that drive...

Comment: That's why you take backups!